# Convert modify time from stat into timestamp

Tags: timestamp

I just started my journey into bash scripting and I wrote a little script which copies certain files to my USB stick and external harddrive as a backup. So far it copies the entire directory with all files including those which I didn't change which naturally takes quite some time. In order to change that, I want it to compare the two files (on the pc and on the USB stick) with regards to the time when they were modified. So now I wonder how I can convert the output from

> stat -c %y /test_folder/test.txt

into the format "YmDHMS"? Or maybe someone knows a better way to compare the files.

Comment: I think you want to have a look at the `rsync` command that you can set to only update if the source file is newer than the one on the backup

Answer (score 0):

For comparison purposes you are probably better off using seconds since epoch (i.e. `stat -a %Y`) directly or even simpler use one of the bash built-in file tests `[[ FILE1 -nt FILE2 ]]` or `[[ FILE1 -ot FILE2 ]]` instead:

```
   file1 -nt file2
          True if file1 is newer (according  to  modification  date)  than
          file2, or if file1 exists and file2 does not.
   file1 -ot file2
          True  if file1 is older than file2, or if file2 exists and file1
          does not.
```

---

However since the question as asked is about conversion, since `%y` is modification time, if you have a recent version of GNU `date` you could cheat and use that instead. From `man date`:

```
-r, --reference=FILE
       display the last modification time of FILE
```

So

```
$ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -r file
20170111075620
```

Alternatively, you could pass the seconds-since-epoch from `stat` to `date`:

```
$ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S -d "@$(stat -c '%Y' file)"
20170111075620
```

Comment: The @ in the argument to the -d option makes a world of a difference, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For comparing modification (or access or inode change) time of files, you should use seconds since Epoch, it is easier to handle in comparisons. `stat`'s `-c` option has `%Y` format specifier for getting the modification time in seconds since Epoch.

To compare two files based on modification time, you can write a small function:

```
chk_mod () { (( $(stat -c '%Y' "$1") > $(stat -c '%Y' "$2") )) && echo "$1 is newer" \
            || echo "$2 is newer" ;}
```

Input the two input files as first and second positional parameters, and the function will output which one is newer; when they have exactly the same modification times, no output will be shown.

**Example:**

```
$ chk_mod () { (( $(stat -c '%Y' "$1") > $(stat -c '%Y' "$2") )) && echo "$1 is newer" || echo "$2 is newer" ;}

$ chk_mod foobar spamegg 
spamegg is newer
```

Comment: Works for me. Though, I'm using rsync now, since it is easier to handle.